# Finite Automata

Tags: computer-science, regular-language, finite-automata

How to Design a DFA over the alphabet {0,1}:
The set of all strings such that the number of 1's is even and the number of 0's is a multiple of 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use modulo counters in your states like this:

state q[k,l] stands for k is the number of 1s read mod 2, and l the number of 0s read mod 3.

q[0,0] is the start state, q[1,2] is the unique accepting state. There are six states overall, the transitions should be obvious.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Will try to design the DFA.